# compare unsorted array jquery and get index

Tags: jquery, arrays, indexing

Is there any way i can get the index of unsorted value in the array using jQuery? The value that i want is the index of the first and second number that is not same. The array value is same on both side, i just want to get unsorted array values.

```
var arrA = [1,2,3,4];
var arrB = [2,1,3,4];
var c = [0,1]; //expected result
```

i had tried this but it's not working. it loops everything.

```
var position = [];

    $.each(arrA, function(i, val) {   
        var result = []
        $.each(arrB, function(i2, val2) {   
            if(val!==val2){
                result.push(i2)
                // console.log(val, val2)                    
            }

        });
        position.push(result)
    });

    console.log(position)
```

Answer (score 0):

## With jQuery

```js
const sorted = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const unsorted = [2, 1, 3, 4];
let c = [];

$.each(sorted, i => {
  if (sorted[i] !== unsorted[i]) {
    c.push(i);
  }
});

console.log(c);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

## JavaScript only, with a `for` loop

```js
var arrA = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var arrB = [2, 1, 3, 4];
var c = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arrA.length; i++) {
  if (arrA[i] !== arrB[i]) {
    c.push(i);
  }
}

console.log(c);
```

## When you only have the `unsorted` array

And if you only have the *unsorted array* and want to find out what are the indeces of unsorted items, you can create a sorted array then apply the same logic as before

```js
const arr = [2, 1, 3, 4];
const sorted = [...arr].sort();
var c = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] !== sorted[i]) {
    c.push(i);
  }
}

console.log(c);
```

Comment: My pleasure. Make sure you mark this as answered so other user can know the answer too. Cheers